# zimlet, How I can get a list of folders?

Tags: javascript, ajax, zimbra, zimlet

I am new to zimbra and want to create my own zimlet.
I need a list of existing folders in the account where it runs
then I'll give in html format on a dialog window.

I already learned to make the dialog with the example of SimpleDialog

but I do not know how to bring a list of existing folders, especially custom folders

thanks

Could this server?

```
// map name to ID
 ZmFolder.QUERY_ID = {};
 (function() {
    for (var i in ZmFolder.QUERY_NAME) {
        ZmFolder.QUERY_ID[ZmFolder.QUERY_NAME[i]] = i;
    }
 })();
```

thank's  And how can it be implemented in a zimlet?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the code for listing folders? or the zimbra cli?

/opt/zimbra/bin/zmmailbox -z -m @ gaf

```
 https://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/Zmmailbox
 https://files.zimbra.com/docs/soap_api/8.6.0/api-reference/index.html
```

Find/Search for *GetAll*